# Word2vec representation used for RNNs turn a word into a scalar or a vector?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language, word2vec

Based on [this post on quora.com](http://www.quora.com/How-does-word2vec-work) and other sources I got the impression that each word in the word2vec representation is represented by a vector containing e.g. 500 dimensions. However, when looking into the code on sentiment analysis from the tutorial at [deeplearning.net](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html), I've found that each sentence is simply captured in a vector with dimensions of ~40-80. One such example is below:

```
x = [17, 25, 769, 83, 3, 14, 80, 62, 3221, 5, 928, 3, 1782, 6, 1, 1, 771, 24, 3350, 7, 1112, 228, 5, 3978, 4, 17, 25, 1212, 80, 6, 189, 7, 62, 1293, 5, 514, 4, 2, 131, 10, 1146, 480, 59, 413, 213, 117, 3, 14, 824, 69, 611, 2, 239, 73, 222, 72, 2338, 2, 67, 147, 4, 15, 1164, 123, 17, 10, 6, 100, 111, 23, 45, 228, 25, 4427, 8, 1131, 73, 31, 4]
y = [1]
```

With a sentence consisting of many words, it is clear that this vector cannot represent each word using 200 or 500 dimensions. Instead it seems that each word is approxmiated by a single scalar value. How can this be?

Comment: where did you see the 40-80 figure? The only data on size I could find is in lstm.py. Function  def train_lstm
    dim_proj=128,  # word embeding dimension and LSTM number of hidden units. That is, they use 128 dimensions vector for each word

Comment: If you look at the values for `x` and `y` at roughly line 565 in `lstm.py` in a debugger (or print them), you'll see that they are lists with each element being similar to the `x` and `y` in my original post. Each element in `x` is a single sentence captured in a single vector with ~40-80 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each word in a given sentence is converted into an index on an array that contains a dictionary of all words in your corpus.  This is your variable length x vector and is separate from the word2vec embeddings.

This index is also used to lookup the associated fixed length word2vec  vectors in a lookup table during training and prediction.

This [RNN deeplearning tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rnnslu.html) explains it better with code samples.

In [torch](http://torch.ch/) this word index lookup is handled by the [Lookup table](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/24fd108ef05d24cf93a7649ba39191556f45ee76/doc/convolution.md#nn.LookupTable) layer.

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me find where in the accompanying scripts for http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html I set the number of dimensions for the word2vec representation?